# SDL Deployer 2013

Tags: 2013, 2013-sp1, deployer

[image]

We are on Tridion 2013 and deployer stopped working recently. I tried checking the logs in event viewer and folder specified in logback.xml, but no luck. I tried creating the Deployer from scratch but still the same. Please suggest.

Comment: 404 means it's an invalid url. Looks like someone may have stopped the server or uninstalled it

Comment: add a test.html page to check that the webserver is running, check your firewall rules are not blocking